# C# Regex, Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings in the following format

```
    _AUTO_(123,SomeString)
```

and I am trying to extract 123 from the above string using regex. The regex, that I am using is:

```
    const string pattern = @"\_AUTO\_\(?<number>(\d)+\,";
    foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(line, pattern)) { 
       Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["number"].Value); 
    }
```

I am getting Unrecognized escape sequence \_ error exception. 
Could someone please point me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the exception self explanatory?  `_` is not an escape sequence, _don't escape it!_

Comment: Common sense is what tells you the world is flat?

Comment: It's not obvious to me, even with Exception message. I'm still not sure how the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#character_escapes)  or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx) is telling me that "\_" is not allowed. It's allowed in Javascript Regular Expressions. Even the accepted answer says "You don't need to escape the underscore". Shouldn't it say, "You **must not** escape the underscore"?

Comment: Even the Microsoft documentation says when the backslash is "followed by a character that is not recognized as an escaped character, matches that character.". Isn't that exactly what OP is trying to do; match the "_"?

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to escape the underscore (or, for that matter, the comma). Change your regex to:

```
@"_AUTO_\(?<number>(\d)+,"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. The exception is gone but now it is not printing the matches. :-(

Comment: I think you and I also did the named capture wrong. Try this: `@"_AUTO_\((?<number>(\d)+),"`

Comment: Why have you both retained the `(\d)`? Why not simplify the expression slightly to `@"_AUTO_\((?<number>\d+),"`?

Comment: let me kiss you :* .. I had been trying to see if my escaping is valid and working properly or not. Everything was fine, but still `Unrecognized escape sequence` exception. I skipped escaping `_` and `,` as you mentioned, and it worked